# Partitoning the DbSet manually in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am not too sure what the title of this question should, but here it is.

I am trying to design a Code-First model in .Net in which I would want the `DbSets` to be auto generated. I have about 15 classes who differ from each other only based upon a constant property (a `string`). And in the Application's DbContext I have 15 properties each of the same type but different name (which suits the data it will be storing). The reason for such separation is for performance. So if I want data from class with `key1`, I would look in to the corresponding `DbSet`.

So here's what I have for Model now:

```
public class MyClassKey1: MyClassBase
{
    public override string Key = "key1"
}

public class MyClassKey2: MyClassBase
{
    public override string Key = "key2"
}
// and so on this MyClassKey15 ..
```

The MyClassBase merely ensures that each child class overrides the property `Key`.
And the ApplicationDbContext looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbSet<MyClassKey1> Key1Objects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyClassKey2> Key2Objects { get; set; }
    // and so on till Key15Objects.. 
}
```

Though this is suitable, I can not see myself writing efficient code for the `DataAcessLayer`. Is there a better way to implement this? Perhaps a better design pattern or approach?

**Update1**: I think what I need is a way to simulate the table partitioning the MS SQL provides out of the box. I would not be using MS SQL server, or a database that provide table partitioning out of the box. Something like a small scale database, SQlite on a limited hardware like mobile phone.

Comment: How are you going to use that (some code sample would be good)?

Comment: What code is inefficient and why?

Comment: @Evk , that is where I realized the design is not so usable. If I were to write a SQL query it would be much easier to construct it as a string and then fire it up on the database. But I cannot imagine doing that with EntityFramework.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, in continuation to my above comment. E.g `string.Format("Select * from MyClassKey{0}", myDynamicKeyVariable)` . How would I be able to do this?

Comment: I think I need to implement table partitioning, like in MS SQL. Please see the updated question

Comment: @bit: to be honest i don't understand the reason for this data model. It will generate 15 tables with the same columns which is normally a bad design. You should really consider to use one table with another column `ClassType`(or something like that). Then you can select all relevant records with an easy statement: `SELECT * from t WHERE ClassType=@type`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, my existing implementation already has that, but I need to speed up things. So by having such indexed tables, my queries would be faster. hence the quest.

Comment: Usually table partitioning might improve perfomance on really HUGE tables (say close to terabyte), which seems not your case (sqlite on small hardware). Most likely you just need proper index on your table.

Comment: Yes, I need to have that improvement on a small scale hardware. What I am thinking about is using the `MyClassBase` as the type of all 15 `DbSets` And then maintaining a static and in memory Dictionary of the `Key` to `DbSet<MyClassKey>` and using that to fire queries.. Would that be good?

Comment: I already have index on the `Key` column but they are not good enough, since the hardware.. May be I am pushing it to the limit..

Comment: Well you better first ensure (with raw sql queries) that your partitioning makes sense...

Comment: They seem to make sense. If I were to find records corresponding to the Key 12, my query qould look like `string.Format("Select * from MyClassKey{0}", 12)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with Partners and Customers (of partners), they both had Billing Addresses, so my first approach was to derive the partners and customers from something like an AddressEntity.

After a while it seemed much easier to use aggregation instead of inheritance. I have a table with Billing Addresses and a Partner has a foreign key BillingAddresId to the BillingAddress. The customer had the same structure:

```
public class Partner
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string NaturalKey { get; set; }

    // foreign key to address
    public long BillingAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }

    // a partner has a collection of customers:
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IId, ITerminable
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // foreign key to partner:
    public long PartnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Partner Partner { get; set; }

    // foreign key to address
    public long BillingAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class BillingAddress
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Preposition { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Note: because you can't say whether a billing address belongs to a Partner or a customer the Billing Address doesn't have a foreign key to the Partner nor the customer

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BillingAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This has the effect that three tables will be made: one with Billing Addresses, one with Partners and one with Customers. Each Partner and each Customer will have a foreign key to a record in the table of billing addresses. Whenever a partner or a customer is added with a filled billing address, the billing address is automatically added to the table of billing addresses and its Id is assigned to the BillingAddressId.

```
public Partner CreatePartner(...)
{
    BillingAddress address = CreateAddress(...)
    return new Partner()
    {
        BillingAddress = address,
        OtherProperty = ...,
    };
}

public Partner AddPartner(...)
{
    Partner partnerToAdd = CreatePartner(...);
    // don't allow partners without addresses:
    if (partnerToAdd.BillingAddress == null) throw ...

    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    {
        var addedPartner = dbContext.Partners.Add(partnerToAdd);
        dbContext.Savechanges();
        return addedPartner;
    }
}

public Partner RetrievePartner(long partnerId)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    {
        return dbContext.Partners
            .Include(p => p.BillingAddress)
            .Single(p => p.Id == partnerId);
    }
}
```

The include statement makes that the billing address is included in the same database query as the one where the partner data is retrieved.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see this answering what I need. Please see the updated question and comments.